# Selenium in build.gradle failed after Migrating code to AndroidX

Tags: java, android, selenium, build.gradle, androidx

When i go to upgrade my project libraries to AndroidX. Migration to AndroidX is done.

Now on this line in build.gradle:

```
compileOnly files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar')
```

I am getting this build error

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> >     Failed to transform file 'selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar} using transform
> >     JetifyTransform
> >     Failed to transform '/home/sajid/Git/project-android/app/libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar'
> >     using Jetifier. Reason: duplicate entry: META-INF/DEPENDENCIES. (Run
> >     with --stacktrace for more details.)

What should i do to make selenium work.

For more information i am using selenium for appium UI Tests. And i am adding Appium as:

```
    compileOnly 'io.appium:java-client:6.1.0'
compileOnly files('libs/java-client-6.1.0.jar')
```

Have a look please where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no help from here :(

So after alot of strugle and testing out different versions. I got success and Appium/Seleniu tests are working now.

To resolve this. i removed jar files of appium:java-client and selenium-server-standalone.

Then instead of Selenium Standalon server. I now use selenium-android-driver with the latest version.

Which was still not workable. i was getting error on WebDriver.Wait. Which i resolve by depreciating the version of guava for 28 to 21 as:

```
api 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
```

And then add git repo address of appium-java and selenium-android to add them in project as:

```
testImplementation 'io.appium:java-client:7.1.0'
testImplementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-android-driver:2.39.0'
```

Then under UI Test classes. I changed AppiumDriver and WebDriver to AndroidDriver as:

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now its working